# Sliding window and historical data

Tags: time-series, forecasting

In my problem I have a longer period of historical data of a time series. I need to predict for some specific points in time in the future. For these points in time five previous values are *also* available.

So far my approach was to use a sliding window of size five, use lag features and apply machine learning methods.

However I have a feeling that when doing like this I am not exploiting the historical data to the full extent. (The methods see only one sliding window at a time.)

I am now looking for some method (or ideas to design my own) which takes as an input historical data *and* measurements just before the time point I need to predict for.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the same measurements available for the future point in time, for which you already have the 5 mentioned values?

Comment: @geekoverdose Yes, I have exact same data for historical and future points in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the same information available in your past data as for your future data (both in the form of time series), you could use a number of sequence data/time series based model types to predict your target variable. The core difference is that those models "remember" information between samples, so don't only derive the output on from the $N$ input features of the current input, but also from input they've seen before. Such models range from e.g. [Hidden Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) to [Recurrent Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) - but there are many more suitable model types, with different advantages/disadvantages depending on the details of your problem.

PS: have a look at e.g. [this answer](https://www.quora.com/Data-Science-Can-machine-learning-be-used-for-time-series-analysis) or [this slideset](http://www.ulb.ac.be/di/map/gbonte/ftp/time_ser.pdf) for some more details and further references.

Comment: The problem is: I have a big gap in between. The data looks like this: 5 years of historical data, then gap, then 3 month, let's say May, June, July and I need to predict for August. I haven't seen models which can swallow such a big gap in between.

Comment: I see, your assumption is that the relation of month $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$ to $m_4$ is the same for historical data (5 years ago) and current data. If this assumption is correct, then the model should learn to predict month $m_4$ from $m_1$ to $m_3$ with both historical and current data. I don't see why this should not conceptually be possible using sequence based models (you don't use the 5 years gap explicitly).